Why data type will change in Customized layer in TensorFlow if the code has for i in range(x):
MyClass is
class MyCalcSqureLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, shape ):
        super(MyCalcSqureLayer, self).__init__()
        self.total = self.add_weight(initializer="zero", shape=shape, trainable=False)

        
    def call(self,inputs):
        print('type=',type(inputs))
        x =inputs.shape[0]
        print(x,type(x))
        for i in range(x): <--- the valiable x's type will be change if this line.
            print(i)
                
        return inputs

When this code is running, the results shows as follows:
 type= <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.SymbolicTensor'>
 None <class 'NoneType'>

But I commented the line out and the runs show:
 type= <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
 5 <class 'int'>

My enciroments information as follow:
tensorflow 2.17.0
python 3.11.8
PC MacOS M2
I would like to get the type int and want to make a code the follow rows tensor.

To work with the integer value in both eager and symbolic modes, you could use 'tf.shape(inputs)[0]', which will return a tensor, and then you can convert it to an integer in eager execution using '.numpy()'.

Thanks Sagar . You advice is work for me.
